# Rails MultiSelect (Array) not converting to String Properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I cant seem to get my array to string converted properly. I'm using rails multiselect:

**Views:**

```
<%= f.select :foo, [ ['a'], ['b'], ['c'] ], {:prompt => "Select an alpha"}, {:multiple => true} %>
```

**Controller:**

```
params.require(:bar).permit(:foo => [])
```

**JS View:**

```
foo.toString() // Gives: ["", "a", "c"]
```

How to get `foo` to nicely formatted as `a, c`? If selected `a` and `c`?

In the rails console, it shows as:

```
"[\"\", \"a\", \"c\"]"
```

**EDIT:**

My table column is string :(

**EDIT #2:**

I have dropped the foo column:

```
remove_column :bar, :foo
```

**with:**

```
add_column :bar, :foo, :text, array: true, default: []
```

Now my `rails c` looks like:

```
[0] "",
[1] "a",
[2] "c"
```

**How to get:**

```
[0] "a",
[1] "c"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a before_validation callback in your Model to remove blanks before saving to the database:

```
before_validation :remove_blanks_in_foo

private

def remove_blanks_in_foo
  self.foo = foo.reject(&:blank?)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd rather use `foo.delete_if(&:blank?)` because I can read it easily! But yours do worked.